# Confusing between "As" and "Is"

Tags: as, listening

I came across that sentence while watching martin mystery --link of the episode below-- 
" if you think I am so naive is to be fooled by another one of your tricks!"

At first I was going to ask about "is to be" because I couldn't get the grammar behind it in this sentence but once i crossed out "so naive" it got clear and now I am wondering how could "so naive" fit like that in the middle of the sentence, it sounds really weird to me.

https://youtu.be/o9ZBwpyERhA

Sentence said between minute 9:42 and 9:48

Edit: I changed "very" to "so" to be more convenient with what said in the video

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much more likely the piece of dialogue is as follows:

> ... if you think I am really **so** naive **as** to be fooled by another one of your tricks!

Meaning:

> ... If you think I am so naive that I would be fooled by another one of your tricks!

In fact, I just listened to it and my take is correct.

Comment: Oh I feel so stupid, I thought it was a new grammatical rule I didn't know about when in reality I couldn't hear the difference between 'as' and 'is'.  Thanks alot for answering me!

Comment: @Manar please mark the answer "Accepted" (the tick on the left of the answer) if it satisfies your question.